# Can Sasuke use his Rinnegan to bring Jiraiya and Itachi back to life?

Tags: naruto

After achieving both Rinnegan and Sharingan in his left eye, can Sasuke use Rinne Rebirth Jutsu to bring Jiraiya and Itachi back to life?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about [Gedō — Rinne Tensei no Jutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_%E2%80%94_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique), then there are some restrictions:

- First of all you need the body of the dead person

  > To perform this technique, the user summons the King of Hell, which then releases the souls of the deceased from its mouth. With their rejuvenated bodies acting as an anchor, the deceased individuals' souls are able to leave even the crossroad between life and the afterlife, returning back to their physical vessels.
- The person who used the jutsu dies

  > Ultimately, once the technique is finished, the user inevitably dies.

I don't know about Itachi's body, but Jiraiya's was lost that even Kabuto was unable to find it.

Comment: May be Jiraya is alive.But even after using the justu is Sasuke dies then Naruto can save him

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? You are essentially quoting from the wiki, so you have to cite the source.

Comment: Plot twist: Naruto dies in the end, Sasuke revives him and dies himself. (I didn't watch much naruto.)

Comment: @nhahtdh I reverted your edit because all you've edited was the name of the jutsu and one grammatical error (i'm not native english speaker). In rest you simply deleted what I wrote and added EXACTLY the same text.

Comment: @Kira-TheGod: You should look at the markdown diff. I'm only formatting the quotes (indent it in along with the bullet point) and the name of the jutsu. The normal diff is misleading, since the indentation causes change in the HTML structure of the post, which results in a significant visual difference.

Comment: Why is it that they die when that jutsu is used. Konan notes "if he uses it now at these chakra levels" in one translation, as in he did not have enough chakra to use it, but he did and died, presumably of chakra exhaustion like kakashi had just done. just a page earlier, she also said that a master of the six paths controls life and death, noting nothing about sacrifice to do so. Plus obito lived after using it, with his only drawback being the same as it was before using it, inability to move due to 10 tails extraction.

Comment: Jiraiya most likely did not die from the pains all stabbing and beating him. He was still able to move and talk and it was probably most likely that he died from the pressure of the ocean. It would be quite difficult to retrieve his body or at least what may have been left of it considering there are many things that could have happened to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes he can use this technique 
.but  he  needs their  bodies  and  I think  he  can  escape  death  if he  uses  the  power  of  all tailed  beast  that  Naruto  has or the  ten tails since  they posses  immeasurable  amount  of chakra,as for  jiraya  that's  impossible  because  his  body  is not available.